# App/website model not showing on Alexa Developer console

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-voice-service

I am trying to connect my alexa skill with the custom android app. For that I need App/Website model in Alexa developers console. But I can't find it. Is there anything I need to do to activate that model option.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Alexa for Apps is a currently only available to select developers as part of a developer preview program. To use this feature, you must [register for the preview](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/alexa/alexa-skills-kit/get-deeper/response-api/alexa-for-apps).

For more information, please see the documentation here:
https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/alexa-for-apps/use-developer-console.html